# Who compiled and arranged the Ashkenaz Kinnos?

Tags: jewish-books, tisha-bav, authorship

The [Kinnos](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%91_(%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96)) read nowadays on Tisha B'Av seem to have been standardized more or less amongst Ashkenazim to the same 40-odd kinnos, but it obviously wasn't always the case. Many of the Kinnos were written in the past 1000 years by authors across Europe. Undoubtedly there have been hundreds, if not thousands, of dirges written about tragedies which have befallen the Jewish people throughout our history. Yet only a very limited selection of kinnos have made their way into [almost](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/HTK.html) [every](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/holidays/kinnot-selichot/mesorat-harav-kinot.html) [Ashkenaz](http://www.eichlers.com/kinos-hebrew-only-paperback.html) Kinnos publication [available](https://mekorjudaica.com/qinvt-ltweh-bab.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwn6DMBRC0ARIsAHZtCeNiLU7LkgPOzkLnkkTYl06hgb9lqRoBWfnS0G6HxL4-0d3Nw5K9TKgaAjKxEALw_wcB) [today](https://mekorjudaica.com/kinnos-for-tishah-b-av.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwn6DMBRC0ARIsAHZtCePoDoAFSAO2GhZMu72YKEv3HJIVdKoaMCkE3h6llujicU70npkuaOQaAkpPEALw_wcB).

Who compiled and arranged the Ashkenaz Kinnos the way we have them today, and when did this take place?

Comment: Are there Sephardic Kinnos that are different than the Ashkenazic versions? I wasn't aware there was another compilation.

Comment: @Earl Apparently so. Wiki has an extensive list of Kinnot for Sephardim and Edot Mizrach: http://bit.ly/2wopYCF and here is one publication of Sepharadi Kinnot: https://mekorjudaica.com/kinot-for-tishah-b-av-sephardi-edot-hamizrach.html

Comment: Have you checked the Art Scroll Kinot? I think he attributes most of them to Rav Elazar Hakalir.

Comment: @DanF many of them are indeed written by R Eleazar HaKalir. Your point?

Comment: Huh?? Didn't you ask who compiled most of the Kinnot?

Comment: @DanF correct. I didn't ask who authored each of the Kinnos. I asked who compiled them. As I mentioned in the question, there were undoubtedly thousands of dirges written throughout history. I would like to know who selected these 40-some Kinnos to include in the Tisha B'Av Kinnos recitation.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could say that the Kinnos were compiled by one person. It's more that certain sad poems were written to commemorate disasters and those communities began reciting them on Tishah B'Av, which spread to other communities.